# fetch --nohooks chromium : Permission Denied?

Tags: git, unix, browser, fetch, chromium

So, I'm trying to check out chromium, including all its dependencies. According to the chromium website, the following command should create a new folder named src in my current working directory.

I'm issuing this command in my depot_tools folder:

```
$fetch chromium --nosvn=True
```

But, I'm getting an error message showing that I do not permission to do so. Any clues why?

Here's the actual message:

```
Running: gclient config --spec 'solutions = [{u'"'"'managed'"'"': False, u'"'"'name'"'"': u'"'"'src'"'"', u'"'"'url'"'"': u'"'"'https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git'"'"', u'"'"'custom_deps'"'"': {}, u'"'"'deps_file'"'"': u'"'"'.DEPS.git'"'"', u'"'"'safesync_url'"'"': u'"'"''"'"'}]'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/git/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2012, in <module>
    sys.exit(Main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/usr/local/git/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2000, in Main
    return dispatcher.execute(OptionParser(), argv)
  File "/usr/local/git/depot_tools/subcommand.py", line 245, in execute
    return command(parser, args[1:])
  File "/usr/local/git/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 1631, in CMDconfig
    client.SaveConfig()
  File "/usr/local/git/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 1148, in SaveConfig
    self.config_content)
  File "/usr/local/git/depot_tools/gclient_utils.py", line 137, in FileWrite
    with codecs.open(filename, mode=mode, encoding='utf-8') as f:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 878, in open
    file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './.gclient'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/git/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 302, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/git/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 298, in main
    return run(options, spec, root)
  File "/usr/local/git/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 292, in run
    return checkout.init()
  File "/usr/local/git/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 113, in init
    self.run_gclient('config', '--spec', self.spec['gclient_spec'])
  File "/usr/local/git/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 75, in run_gclient
    return self.run(cmd_prefix + cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/git/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 65, in run
    return subprocess.check_call(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('gclient', 'config', '--spec', "solutions = [{u'managed': False, u'name': u'src', u'url': u'https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git', u'custom_deps': {}, u'deps_file': u'.DEPS.git', u'safesync_url': u''}]")' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what's the cwd when you running `$fetch chromium --nosvn=True`?
From the trace, looks like you do not have write permission to write file `./.glcient`.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the script in another directory.

If you type `ls` and see `depot_tools` folder, run the script there.